# Hook for saving an image after editing

Tags: images

Is there any hook which is triggered when an image is edited (crop/re-size whatever)? I need to send an email notification to an admin user when an image will be edited (crop/re-size whatever). I need to get media/attachment id as well which have to be sent in email.

I need your advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`wp_save_image_editor_file` filter fires after.

```
add_filter( 'wp_save_image_editor_file', 'custom_wp_save_image_editor_file', 10, 5 );
function custom_wp_save_image_editor_file( $saved, $filename, $image, $mime_type, $post_id ){
    //Your logic here   

    return $saved;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You might try out the `image_editor_save_pre` filter:

```
add_filter( 'image_editor_save_pre', 'custom_image_editor_save_pre', 10 , 2 );
function custom_image_editor_save_pre( $image, $post_id){
    // your stuff here

    return $image;
}
```

This filter seems to be called when you crop/rotate the image and press the *Save* button (and it's a pre-filter)

The `$image` is an object of type `WP_Image_Editor_GD` and here is an example of how it might look like in the filter:

```
WP_Image_Editor_GD Object
(
    [image:protected] => Resource id #172
    [file:protected] => /absolute/path/to/wordpress/install/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/car.jpg
    [size:protected] => Array
        (
            [width] => 220
            [height] => 330
        )

    [mime_type:protected] => image/jpeg
    [default_mime_type:protected] => image/jpeg
    [quality:protected] => 90
)
```

and `$post_id` is the attachment id.

There might be other better hooks to look for, but I found this one in

```
/wp-admin/includes/image-edit.php
```

in this function:

```
/**
 * Saves Image to File
 *
 * @param string $filename
 * @param WP_Image_Editor $image
 * @param string $mime_type
 * @param int $post_id
 * @return boolean
 */
function wp_save_image_file( $filename, $image, $mime_type, $post_id ) {
        if ( $image instanceof WP_Image_Editor ) {
                $image = apply_filters('image_editor_save_pre', $image, $post_id);
                $saved = apply_filters('wp_save_image_editor_file', null, $filename, $image, $mime_type, $post_id);
```