# Admin hook after editing an image?

Tags: admin, media

Is there a hook for getting a the filename that was just saved by the admin media edit screen, say after image rotation?

I saw [Hook for saving an image after editing](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/111953/hook-for-saving-an-image-after-editing) but it just filters the file and it happens *before* the file save.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I've missed something in the flow of this, It seems the [mentioned WPSE answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/111958/118366) is correct.

The filter hook referenced, [`wp_save_image_editor_file`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_save_image_editor_file/), is applied in the [`wp_save_image_file()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.8/src/wp-admin/includes/image-edit.php#L289) function when dealing with an instance of [WP_Image_Editor](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Image_Editor) class; [giving access to](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.8/src/wp-admin/includes/image-edit.php#L289) `$filename` (trac link for below):

```
* @param mixed           $override  Value to return instead of saving. Default null.
312                  * @param string          $filename  Name of the file to be saved.
313                  * @param WP_Image_Editor $image     WP_Image_Editor instance.
314                  * @param string          $mime_type Image mime type.
315                  * @param int             $post_id   Post ID.
316                  */
317                 $saved = apply_filters( 'wp_save_image_editor_file', null, $filename, $image, $mime_type, $post_id );
```

That function calls class method [`save()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.8/src/wp-includes/class-wp-image-editor.php#L77) which provides no access.

```
76          /**
77           * Saves current image to file.
78           *
79           * @since 3.5.0
80           * @access public
81           * @abstract
82           *
83           * @param string $destfilename
84           * @param string $mime_type
85           * @return array|WP_Error {'path'=>string, 'file'=>string, 'width'=>int, 'height'=>int, 'mime-type'=>string}
86           */
87          abstract public function save( $destfilename = null, $mime_type = null );
```

So while it is not after the save, it is the last moment of the name before being saved, and the filter's usage is intended to be able to skip that `save()` call.
Regarding first (null) parameter:

> Returning a non-null value will short-circuit the save method, returning that value instead.

Comment: To clarify: this hook is after the Save button in editor has been clicked, it is just before the `save()` has been called. So not a response of what was saved ( `save()` returns that), and it would the same value.